# CredentialsError: "Missing credentials in config" even though credentials are set

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use an unauthenticated Cognito identity pool to send emails via SES, using a webform. I'm using plain vanilla JS, no Node/jQuery/React.

```
function sendMessage(event) {
  var params = ...;

  AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    region: 'us-west-2',
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      // Unauthenticated pool for sending emails
      IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:foo'
    })
  });

  var SES = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' });
  SES.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  });
}
```

I've set this up as an onsubmit event for the form, but every time it gets submitted, I get a `CredentialsError: "Missing credentials in config"`.

The way I understand it, I shouldn't have to pull down and explicitly set the access and secret keys via a `get()` call. All of the code samples provided in Cognito and general SDK documentation show that you can directly instantiate a service object and start making calls. There also shouldn't be any race conditions, as I found in [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=176098):

> As of v2.1.20 the credentials are fetched lazily when a request is made.

I'm using v2.597. What am I missing here? Why isn't this working?